# Rounding vertices in Illustrator uniformly

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

I have a quick question about creating round objects without the ellipse tool. I often want to round the areas where vertices lie on an object, so I'll attempt to do it by adding a second vertex, only to find that the rounding is not uniform, and it looks like I'm giving my art pimples!

To give you an Idea, I'm drawing the following in Illustrator:

[image: Art]

The eyes in the picture (the three white pieces) consist of only two vertices with specified arcs on each end.

My problem is that the edges are pointed which do not look good when zoomed out, so I'm trying to figure out how to make the two arcs match without a pointed end.

Comment: why not just use the ellipse tool or add the Round Corners effect?

Comment: round corners makes the eye arcs uniform, or at least appeared to. I set the pixels and both sides became the same. 

Is it possible to manipulate the arcs from an ellipse this way?

I feel like it would be distorted as I already attempted doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply select your anchor points and click on "Convert Selected Anchor Points To Smooth" button?

[image]

Comment: I'm not... but glad I could help ^^